# How to read a JSON file from a directory and delete a property from a JSON Array

Tags: java, json, file, directory

I have a workspace.json file stored in Workspace directory. The content of the file is

```json
{
    "projectIDs": [
        1997094642639,
        1997094375447,
        1997034664997
    ],
    "preferences": {
        "entries": {
            "scripting.starred-expressions": {
                "top": 2147483647,
                "list": []
            },
            "scripting.expressions": {
                "top": 100,
                "list": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I acces the file and remove a specific project id "1997094642639" without using its index

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the json and extract the projectIds, you can use the [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) API to remove it.

```
int element = 1997094642639;   
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element);
```